# Direct requests only to one container of the docker swarm service

Tags: docker, load-balancing, docker-swarm

Is it possible to cause docker load balancer which uses round robin to direct requests only one container of global docker service deployed on multiple hosts? If this container goes down, requests will be forwarded to other running containers.

The only way i can think of is using external load balancer like nginx, but requires additional docker service.

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive the same result by using replica mode and only having one replica of the container running. In this case you rely on Docker to ensure that an instance is always available.

Alternatively, the recommended way is to use an external load balancer. Check [Use swarm mode routing mesh](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/) to see the different usages.